# List of symbols marked [[EXPERIMENTAL]] in the documentation

Tags: functions, documentation, built-in-symbols

Some of the built-in Wolfram Language symbols are marked as `[[EXPERIMENTAL]]` in the documentation. For example
[image: Echo documentation]

How can I get a list of all the symbols marked as `[[EXPERIMENTAL]]`?

<sub>(This question is inspired by [this chat message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25578442#25578442) posted by [Mike Honeychurch](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/77/mike-honeychurch).)</sub>

Comment: Maybe someone from WRI can comment on why this change seems to have occurred. In the past experimental stuff had its own context (and the context/add-on still exists)

Comment: Perhaps it's worth mentioning that there are symbols that _were_ experimental but were later removed. For example, [`ToTitleCase`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToTitleCase.html) is still available in the online docs, but not in _Mathematica_ 10.3.0.0 as it was deemed too buggy in that state of development. I have no idea how to scan through the online docs for `[[Experimental]]` symbols.

Comment: @IstvánZachar As `ToTitleCase` is also no longer part of the *ReferencePages\Symbols* folder one probably would have to crawl through the online documentation searching for http://reference.wolfram.com/2013/images/experimental.png. (The image search of Google doesn't find it.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Edit:** This solution no longer works due to changes in the `Entity` framework.
The `"UnderDevelopment"` `EntityClass` no longer exists. It's not part of `EntityClassList["WolframLanguageSymbol"]` or `WolframLanguageData["Classes"]` anymore.

---

The symbols that are market `[[EXPERIMENTAL]]` in the documentation are in their own entity class of the `"WolframLanguageSymbol"` entity type, which is named `"UnderDevelopment"`.

```
EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", "UnderDevelopment"]
```

[image: UnderDevelopmentEntityClass]

Here is a list of all the 25 symbols currently (version 10.3) in `EntityList[EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", "UnderDevelopment"]]` as a list of links to their online documentation

```
Hyperlink @@@ 
  EntityValue[
   EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", 
    "UnderDevelopment"], {"CanonicalName", "URL"}] // Column
```

[`Autocomplete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Autocomplete.html)
[`AutocompletionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AutocompletionFunction.html)
[`CachePersistence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CachePersistence.html)
[`ContentObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContentObject.html)
[`DeleteSearchIndex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteSearchIndex.html)
[`DimensionReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DimensionReduce.html)
[`DimensionReducerFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DimensionReducerFunction.html)
[`DimensionReduction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DimensionReduction.html)
[`DistanceMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistanceMatrix.html)
[`Echo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Echo.html)
[`EchoFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EchoFunction.html)
[`FindFormula`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFormula.html)
[`FoldPair`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldPair.html)
[`FoldPairList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldPairList.html)
[`LocalObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocalObject.html)
[`SearchIndexObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SearchIndexObject.html)
[`SearchIndices`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SearchIndices.html)
[`Snippet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Snippet.html)
[`TextCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextCases.html)
[`TextPosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextPosition.html)
[`TextSearch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextSearch.html)
[`TextSearchReport`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextSearchReport.html)
[`TextStructure`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextStructure.html)
[`UpdateSearchIndex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpdateSearchIndex.html)
[`WordTranslation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WordTranslation.html)

links to their offline documentation

```
Multicolumn[
 Hyperlink[#, "paclet:ref/" <> #, Appearance -> "DialogBox"] & /@ 
  EntityValue[
   EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", "UnderDevelopment"], 
   "CanonicalName"]]
```

[image: OfflineExperimentalLinks]

and their `"TypesetUsage"` for a quick overview.

```
Column[
 EntityValue[EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", "UnderDevelopment"], "TypesetUsage"],
 Frame -> All, Background -> {{GrayLevel[0.95], LightBlue}}, Spacings -> 1]
```

[image: TypesetUsage]

Comment: Reported `EntityValue[Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", "EchoFunction"], 
 EntityProperty["WolframLanguageSymbol", "TypesetUsage"]]` returning `Missing["NotAvailable"]` as a bug.

Answer (score 13):

List available as `EntityList[EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Experimental"]]`

Answer (score 9):

In Version 11, the `[[EXPERIMENTAL]]` tag appears to be a `Graphics` object. So we can simply look for this object in all the reference page. The downside to this is if the design of this tag ever changes, this solution will need to be updated.

```
(* location of reference pages *)
dir = DirectoryName[FindFile["ReferencePages/Symbols/Integrate.nb"]];

(* position of all GraphicsBox in an experimental ref page *)
Position[Import[dir <> "FeatureExtract.nb"], GraphicsBox[{__}, __]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1}}
> ```

```
(* extract the experimental tag *)
exptag = Extract[Import[dir <> "FeatureExtract.nb"], {1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1}];

(* look for this tag everywhere else *)
syms = Monitor[
 Reap[
  Do[
   file = dir <> name <> ".nb";
   If[FileExistsQ[file] && ! FreeQ[Import[file], exptag],
    Sow[name]
   ],
   {name, Names["System`*"]}
  ]
 ][[-1, 1]],
 name
]
```

> ```
> {AnatomyForm, AnatomyPlot3D, AssumeDeterministic, BatchNormalizationLayer, 
>   BatchSize, BayesianMaximization, BayesianMaximizationObject, 
>   BayesianMinimization, BayesianMinimizationObject, CatenateLayer, 
>   ChannelBase, ChannelDatabin, ChannelListen, ChannelListener, 
>   ChannelListeners, ChannelObject, ChannelPreSendFunction, ChannelSend, 
>   ChannelSubscribers, CloudExpression, CloudExpressions, 
>   ContentFieldOptions, ContentLocationFunction, ConvolutionLayer, CreateChannel, 
>   CreateCloudExpression, CrossEntropyLossLayer, DeconvolutionLayer, 
>   DeleteChannel, DeleteCloudExpression, DotPlusLayer, DropoutLayer, 
>   DynamicImage, ElementwiseLayer, EmbeddingLayer, EntityStore, 
>   FeatureDistance, FeatureExtract, FeatureExtraction, FeatureExtractor, 
>   FeatureExtractorFunction, FileNameForms, FileSystemMap, FileSystemScan, 
>   FindChannels, FlattenLayer, FormControl, GalleryView, HandlerFunctions, 
>   HandlerFunctionsKeys, InitialEvaluationHistory, MaxTrainingRounds, 
>   MaxWordGap, MeanAbsoluteLossLayer, MeanSquaredLossLayer, NetChain, 
>   NetDecoder, NetEncoder, NetExtract, NetGraph, NetInitialize, NetPort, 
>   NetTrain, Pagination, PoolingLayer, RemoveChannelListener, ReshapeLayer, 
>   ResourceData, ResourceObject, ResourceRemove, ResourceSearch, 
>   SearchAdjustment, SearchQueryString, SearchResultObject, SkinStyle, 
>   SoftmaxLayer, SummationLayer, TargetDevice, TotalLayer, URLSubmit, 
>   $AllowExternalChannelFunctions, $ChannelBase, $CookieStore, $EntityStores}
> ```

```
Length[syms]
```

> ```
> 84
> ```

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "11.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)"
> ```

Not a terribly fancy solution, but it works.

Comment: You can also try with `NotebookImport[NotebookFileName[], "ObjectNameGrid"]`, it should be more stable.

Comment: The **Experimental in 10.4** section of [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111872/18476) contains another solution based on searching through the documentation notebooks for the `[[EXPERIMENTAL]]` graphic.

Answer (score 4):

In Mathematica Version 12.1 there is a really elegant way of listing all the Wolfram Language Experimental Symbols and having a convenient link to each ones documentation.

Unfortunately it's dependent on the new entity framework and online connectivity apparently.

```
Hyperlink @@@ EntityValue[EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Experimental"],
                          {"CanonicalName", "URL"}] // Dataset
```

[image: Experimental or UnderDevelopment Functions in 12.1]

Comment: Try this for a nicer looking `Dataset[]`: `Dataset[AssociationThread[{"CanonicalName", "URL"}, #] & /@ MapAt[Hyperlink, EntityValue[EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Experimental"], {"CanonicalName", "URL"}, "EntityAssociation"], {All, -1}]]`,